# How can I declare a template pointer without knowing the type?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, pointers

This is what I would like to do:

```
ExampleTemplate* pointer_to_template;
cin >> number;
switch (number) {
case 1:
    pointer_to_template = new ExampleTemplate<int>();
    break;
case 2:
    pointer_to_template = new ExampleTemplate<double>();
    break;
}
pointer_to_template->doStuff();
```

This doesn't compile because the template type must be specified when declaring the pointer. (`ExampleTemplate* pointer_to_template` should be `ExampleTemplate<int>* pointer_to_template`.) Unfortunately, I don't know the type of the template until it's declared in the switch block. What is the best work around for this situation?

Comment: It sounds like you want runtime polymorphism, i.e. virtual functions.  Templates are about static polymorphism, i.e. types that are known at compile-time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't. `ExampleTemplate<int>` and `ExampleTemplate<double>` are two different, unrelated types. If you always have a switch over several options, use `boost::variant` instead.

```
typedef boost::variant<Example<int>, Example<double>> ExampleVariant;
ExampleVariant v;
switch (number) {
    case 1: v = Example<int>(); break;
    case 2: v = Example<double>(); break;
}
// here you need a visitor, see Boost.Variant docs for an example
```

Another way is to use an ordinary base class with virtual public interface, but I'd prefer `variant`.

```
struct BaseExample {
    virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
    virtual ~BaseExample() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Example : BaseExample { ... };

// ..
BaseExample *obj;
```

Comment: `boost`? isn't it a little bit complicated for a starter?

Comment: let me rephrase: `boost`? it is a little bit complicated for a starter

Comment: @julio.alegria: No, it's not.

Comment: It entirely depends on the newbie in question.  Some people will have little trouble, others would be out of their depth.  The OP will decide to follow up on this, or ask questions, or ignore this answer for something he/she understands more readily.  But it's good to present "the right way" to do this sort of thing, and to introduce new programmers to good libraries (and get them thinking about such libraries) when approaching software problems.

Comment: @julio.alegria: In what way? It's just more C++ black boxes.

Comment: @GMan, I think it isn't a good idea to show C++ as a semi-dynamic typing programming language (at least not for a starter), this could lead to terrible programming mistakes.

Answer (score 10):

You can do something similar by having your template class derive from a regular class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

class ExampleBase{

public:
    virtual ~ExampleBase() {}
    virtual string Get() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class ExampleTemplate : public ExampleBase{

private:
    T data;

public:
    ExampleTemplate(T t) : data(t){}

    string Get(){        
        stringstream s; s << data;
        return s.str();
    }

};

int main(){

    ExampleBase *base;
    int number;
    cout << "> " << flush; cin >> number;

    switch(number){
        case 1:
            base = new ExampleTemplate<int>(42);
            break;
        case 2:
            base = new ExampleTemplate<double>(3.14);
            break;
        default:
            return 1;
    }

    cout << base->Get() << endl;

    delete base;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is not possible. This is becase your `ExampleTemplate` class doesn't exist by itself, only exists when you relate it with a type.

You could get that behaviour using inheritance:

1. Define a `GeneralExampleTemplate` (not a template class).
2. Make `ExampleTemplate<T>` inherit from `GeneralExampleTemplate`.
3. That way you can create a `GeneralExampleTemplate` pointer and assign it with a (for example) `ExampleTemplate<int>`.