# C++ Field holding objects with different template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following setup:

```
// N is the number of rooms
template <size_t N>
class House {
    void printNumberOfRooms();
}


House<1> house1;
House<2> house2;
```

Now I want to have a field that can hold both house1 and house2 and on which I can call house.printNumberOfRooms().

```
House house;
house.printNumberOfRooms();
```

Gave me an "requires template argument" error (obviously).

What is the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to decide what is _best_. Unless you can show specifically what you want to do with this field, you're just asking someone to write you an essay.

Comment: I want to .printNumberOfRooms() on either house1 or house2....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I declare a template pointer without knowing the type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205902/how-can-i-declare-a-template-pointer-without-knowing-the-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`House<1>` and `House<2>` are completely different and incompatible types, therefore you can't store them in a single field.

However what you can do is to give them the same parent class and store them as a pointer to that parent class and make `printNumberOfRooms` virtual. Like this:

```
class BaseHouse{
virtual void printNumberOfRooms();
};
template<size_t N>
class House: public BaseHouse{
virtual void printNumberOfRooms();
};
class C{
BaseHouse * house;
};
```